# Tyrying to do a keyof but restricting valid properties to string types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have run into a little issue with Typescript. I am trying to write some functions to make dealing with my Redux state simpler.

I have this interface that I use to create some Entity State:

```
export interface NormalizedState<T> {
  byId: { [id: string]: T };
  allIds: string[];
}
```

I have some MailState like this:

```
export interface MailState extends NormalizedState<Mail> {
  inbox: string[]
}
```

And I have a function to add to the byId property like this:

```
type StringPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T];

const appendToState = <T, K extends StringPropertyNames<T>>(s: NormalizedState<T>) => (v: T[], p: K) => 
  v.reduce((acc, m) => ({ ...acc, [m[p]]: m }), s.byId);
```

Problem is I get an error in the appendToState function at

```
[m[p]]
```

I get the following error:

> A computed property name must be of type 'string',
>   'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.

So it seems like something in my typings is off. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your types are fine, and for the caller they should work out ok. The problem is that inside a function Typescript can't really do a lot with conditional types. So it will not try to figure out that `T[K]` would work out to a `string`, it just sees the conditional and gives up.

The simple solution is to use a type assertion.

```
const appendToState = <T, K extends StringPropertyNames<T>>(s: NormalizedState<T>) => (v: T[], p: K) => 
  v.reduce((acc, m) => ({ ...acc, [m[p] as string]: m }), s.byId);
```

The other solution is to reverse the way you express the condition. Instead of `K` is any key of `T` that has the type `string`, we can say `T` must have a property `K` of type `string`. This alternate way is easier for the compiler to reason about

```
const appendToState2 = <T extends Record<K, string>, K extends PropertyKey>(s: NormalizedState<T>) => (v: T[], p: K) => 
  v.reduce((acc, m) => ({ ...acc, [m[p]]: m }), s.byId);
```

Comment: Your solution of reversing the condition worked great! I moved the property name to the first argument group, like this appendToState(state, "id"), to help Typescript with figuring out the generic, otherwise I had to do appendToState<Mail, "id">(state).